# .htaccess redirecting to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, slim

I am having an issue with my .htaccess file.  I am using Slim framework and have a number of routes set up that are working fine.

But when you type the webaddress without www. it is redirected to index.php

Example:

https://www.example.com/Route --- Works

[www.example.com/Route](http://www.example.com/Route)         --- Works

https://example.com/Route redirects to https://www.example.com/index.php

example.com/Route  redirects to https://www.example.com/index.php

.htaccress File:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I am pretty sure it is an issue with the .htaccess file but just cant figure it out.

Any help would be great or pointers.

Comment: Did you clear your browser caches?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, do you have any other rules apart from these? OR do you have any other htaccess file in your system too? apart from this one.

Comment: @AmitVerma - I am feeling a bit stupid now ha but that has fixed it.  I changed the order of these two statments thinking that might have fixed it. Would that have caused the issue in the first place?

Comment: If you previously had the canonical redirects after the rewrite to the front-controller then yes, that would have caused the redirect to `index.php`. Since this is a 301 (permanent) redirect the erroneous redirect would have been persistently cached by the browser.